# regex: find the part, which doesn't contain none of some words

Tags: php, regex

how can i much the sentense, if it doesn't contain none of {word1,word2,word3}
where i must put **^** symbol?
i think it must looks like this

```
^([^word1|word2|word3])$
```

but it doesn't work.
could you help? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't the best tool for testing these sorts of conditions, but if you must then you can do it with [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*word1)(?!.*word2)(?!.*word3).*$
```

What you are trying to do won't work because `[^...]` is a negative character class with an unordered list of characters. What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
^([^123dorw|])$
```

Note also that depending on your needs you might also want to include word-boundaries in your regular expression:

```
^(?!.*\bword1\b)(?!.*\bword2\b)(?!.*\bword3\b).*$
```

Comment: @Mark Byers but i need to use ir in .htaccess. 
will it work by ^(?!.*word1)(?!.*word2)(?!.*word3).*$?

Comment: @Syom: Yes it will work depending on what you need. You should try to understand what it means and when and why it works, especially the part about word boundaries before you just copy & paste it into your file.

Comment: thanks much Mark. but it's new for me! i neve  do such things by so.
could you  explain  why ? and . and * in (?!.*word1), and where you "say" 'none of those words'?

Comment: @Syom If this is just for .htaccess, the question should not be tagged PHP. There are tags for htaccess and mod_rewrite, those might be more apt.

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with the use of regex in htaccess, so my thoughts may be bit high level:

what you try looks like kind of:
if sentence contains **not** word1 | **not** word2 | **not** word3
  then do something

i would suggest a solution the way:
if sentence contains word1|word2|word3
  then do nothing
  **else** do something

means don't use the negation in the "query", but in the result, which makes the regex simpler.